# SSIS 2012 Project Deployment Model - Environment Inheritance

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

We have three environments - production, staging, and test. Each environment has multiple databases for our internal back office systems (ie, time collection, accounting, human resources, etc).

For our employee benefits, we create file feeds that get shipped out to our benefit providers to handle enrollment/termination. Prior to SSIS 2012, we had a set of custom SSIS components that centralized configurations - so depending on where we deployed the package, it would automatically pick up the right connection strings.

Now our old way worked, but it has its own difficulties (ie, new developers often forget to set up the package properly and spend time trying to figure it out), so we'd like to move forward with SSIS 2012 and the Project Deployment Model.

I really like the concept of the Environment configurations, but simply creating 3 environments for prod/stage/test doesn't seem like a good idea. A lot of our packages have custom SFTP credentials, file paths to various areas on the network, etc - so those environments would grow very quickly with things that don't really matter to most of our packages.

Is there a way to have one Environment configuration pull in data from another Environment configuration? Something like this would allow me to create a Production Environment config which has the common database servers, and then inherit that within a production config for one of our benefit file feed packages. The benefit file feed package prod config would have all of its other very specific variables.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do what you want with the default options available in the SSIS Catalog. It is however quite easy to modify the SSISDB through T-SQL. But if you really want to go through the trouble of writing something custom depends on how many parameters you expect to use. I don't see any problems with creating just the 3 different environments.

Comment: @JodyT - Well the goal was to not have 3 environment configs, each with well over 50 variables to handle the needs of all of our different packages. Our production environment has numerous systems in place to support our company, so we'd prefer to keep the SSIS Environment Configs focused. But it doesn't look like SSIS 2012 supports this very well. Not that big of a deal.

Comment: Once you have more than a few vars in a package, handling them inside SQL can be a pain, so in that case one strategy I have used is to have one var pointing to a location like a config file or view that holds all the properties, which the ssis package reads in as part of its initialisation. Then in the different environments, you only have one parameter to manage (inside of SQL Server, anyway).

Comment: @meataxe that's pretty much what we were doing before, though we had the config stored in a database vs in a config file. The only thing I don't like is that it does require the SSIS package to include some data flows / logic to pull in this information, and set its connections/vars appropriately. I'd rather let the SSIS package logic focus purely on whatever business need it has, and leave configuration out of it. SSIS is certainly improving.. just..very..slowly :) But at least VS 2012 finally supports BIDS projects.

Answer (score 1):

Probably catalog stored procedures in SSISDB could be an option (e.g. catalog.create_environment, catalog.create_environment_reference, catalog.create_environment_variable)

Comment: That's certainly a possibility - to create some procedures that could automatically build out new environments configurations based upon some others. Especially if it's based off of a table with some triggers, we could build out a nice dependency tree which would give us some nice reports too. Will have to explore this one further, thanks.